# POST request with OAuth

Tags: oauth

I am wondering OAuth signature is related only to URL or related to something inside post data when using POST protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual parameters are defined as the signature base string in the specification:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-3.4.1

The POST body is only included when the criteria in section 3.4.1.3.1 is met:

```
  *  The entity-body is single-part.

  *  The entity-body follows the encoding requirements of the
     "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" content-type as defined by
     [W3C.REC-html40-19980424].

  *  The HTTP request entity-header includes the "Content-Type"
     header field set to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".
```

In other words, if you're posting XML or JSON data, the parameters are not included. However, if it's basic form encoded data it may be.